# How to save generated exe in Run-Time Compilation

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to save to Desktop generated code by CSharpProvider to Desktop. How can I do that?

```
CodeDomProvider codeProvider = CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("CSharp");
string Output = "Out.exe";
Button ButtonObject = (Button)sender;

textBox2.Text = "";
System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters parameters = new CompilerParameters();
//Make sure we generate an EXE, not a DLL
parameters.GenerateExecutable = true;
parameters.OutputAssembly = Output;
CompilerResults results = codeProvider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters, textBox1.Text);

if (results.Errors.Count > 0)
{
    textBox2.ForeColor = Color.Red;
    foreach (CompilerError CompErr in results.Errors)
    {
        textBox2.Text = textBox2.Text +
                    "Line number " + CompErr.Line +
                    ", Error Number: " + CompErr.ErrorNumber +
                    ", '" + CompErr.ErrorText + ";" +
                    Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine;
    }
}
else
{
    //Successful Compile
    textBox2.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
    textBox2.Text = "Success!";
    //If we clicked run then launch our EXE
    if (ButtonObject.Text == "Run") Process.Start(Output);
}
```

I don't want to run it just save it.

Comment: Have you tried setting the out.exe to have a path?

Comment: Yes and it has work thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it . Changed the out.exe to c:\out.exe.